# Are subclass properties preserved if I assign a subclass instance to a property typed as a parent class?

Tags: objective-c, oop, polymorphism

I have a feed that loads a array of:

•`Status` objects

•`PhotoStatus` objects - a subclass of `Status`

When a user clicks on a status in the feed it takes them to `ViewCommentsViewController`  which has the following property that MUST be set in order for the view controller to work:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Status *status;
```

If I pass/assign:

```
  ViewCommentsViewController.status=photoStatus;
```

Can I reliably still preserve the subclass properties of the `photoStatus` some how? Maybe by doing something like `photoStatus *revertedPhotoStatus=status;` in my view controller, or what is the right way to do what im trying to do? I dont want to have multiple view controller classes, and I don't want to go the sloppy route of having both `photoStatus` & `status` properties in my `ViewCommentsViewController`, so how do I reliably allow the loading of multiple types of content that are all subclasses of `Status`?

Comment: Since properties are pointers to objects, the answer is yes.

Comment: Would love you to expand on this a bit, is it perfectly acceptable practice to do something likephotoStatus *revertedPhotoStatus=status;  ?

Comment: Short answer is no.  You'll only get a compiler warning (not an error), something like "Incompatible pointer types assigning to `PhotoStatus *` from `Status *`", but if you think about what this is actually doing, you'll realize this is unsafe.  If you have properties/methods on the subclass, and the containing object expects to have access to those subclass methods (which you've declared by having the property be the subclass, not the parent class), then attempting to reference any of these properties/methods on the parent class will result in a runtime "unrecognized selector" exception.

Comment: In that case you should check that the class of the returned object matches what your code expects in order to not e.g. call non-existent methods. You could also add methods that return `self` casted to a particular subclass and `nil` if the class doesn't match, but there are some issues calling struct-returning methods on nil.

Comment: Can you post this in a answer form that shows me how I could check what type of class viewCommentsViewController.status is reliably?

Comment: im pretty sure even if it is pointing to a photoStatus bc its defined in my viewComments.h as a status it will not allow me access to my subclass properties even if is pointing to a subclass object right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use methods that are defined in the `Status` class but not `PhotoStatus`, you need to check the class of the returned object. To do this, you would normally do something along these lines:

```
Status *status = viewCommentsViewController.status;
if ([[status class] isSubclassOfClass: [PhotoStatus class]])
{
    PhotoStatus *photoStatus = (PhotoStatus *) status;
    // Handle photoStatus.
}
else
{
    // Handle the other case.
}
```

If you want to save a few lines at the call site, you could add accessors like this:

```
@implementation Status
- (PhotoStatus *) asPhotoStatus
{
    return nil;
}
@end

@implementation PhotoStatus
- (PhotoStatus *) asPhotoStatus
{
    return self;
}
@end
```

and then just call

```
[[viewCommentsViewController.status asPhotoStatus] doSomething];
```

**Edit:** Since Xcode 4.2, sending a message to nil should always return a zero value or cause the returned struct to be filled with zeros. (Unfortunately I couldn't find a specification, but [this blog post](http://blog.ioactive.com/2012/11/ios-security-objective-c-and-nil.html) contains a summary.)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I reliably still preserve the subclass properties of the photoStatus some how

Yes, this just happens automatically. It's called *polymorphism*: a thing is the thing it is, not the thing you happen to type it as. So if you assign an actual PhotoStatus object to a variable typed as a Status, it remains a PhotoStatus under the hood. This mechanism is absolutely crucial; without it, subclass instances would not be very useful!

Note, however, that in order to *treat* your Status-typed object as a PhotoStatus object, if that is what it really is under the hood, you will need to cast it down to a PhotoStatus object. And if you do this and this happens *not* to be a PhotoStatus object, you may be heading for a crash later when a PhotoStatus message is sent to an object that is not in fact a PhotoStatus.

Comment: So what kind of if would  I do to figure out which kind of object is underlying prior to casting?

Comment: You can use `respondsToSelector:` for something that only the subclass knows how to do, for example. Or use `isKindOfClass:`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In the best of all worlds, you wouldn't need to test what kind of class something is.  Instead, the class receiving the object would declare a pointer to a base class that implemented all necessary methods.

The implementations would be different but, in this case, a `ViewCommentsViewController` could make consistent calls to any kind of `Status` and know that the methods existed.

Another way of structuring things to assure this would be by using a protocol.  That would make your declaration something like `@property (nonatomic,strong) id<StatusProvider> status;`.

I've typed `isKindOfClass` far too often to present myself as any kind of purist, but it's nice to use a clean approach when possible.

Comment: There are 5 different types of content, they can all be displayed in a single viewCommentsviewController IF I know what type of status it is, but to say I should just dump the properties of ALL the types of statuses into one model feels bad practice.

Comment: It works better with behavior than direct access to properties.  Consider NSObject's `description` as an example.  Many objects have many ways of providing one but there's a default and there's a standard return type.  All else is up to the implementation.